# How to identify value changed in the same column using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2016

I need you help to calculate the number of days between 2 rows based on change in value in the same column

Here's my source table

```
USER_ID LOGIN_DATE  USER_AGNT_STR
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100033  2020-02-18  {'HTTP_USER_AGENT':'/x.x.x Version x.0, build 14623 (iPhoneX;Apple iPhone10,3; iOS 13.3.1)'}
100033  2020-02-19  {'HTTP_USER_AGENT':'/x.x.x Version x.0, build 14623 (iPhoneX;Apple iPhone10,3; iOS 13.3.1)'}
100033  2020-02-19  {'HTTP_USER_AGENT':'/x.x.x Version x.1, build 14624 (iPhoneX;Apple iPhone10,3; iOS 13.3.1)'}
100056  2020-02-20  {'HTTP_USER_AGENT':'/x.x.x Version x.0, build 14623 (iPhoneX;Apple iPhone10,3; iOS 13.3.1)'}
100056  2020-02-21  {'HTTP_USER_AGENT':'/x.x.x Version x.1, build 14624 (iPhoneX;Apple iPhone10,3; iOS 13.3.1)'}
```

I wrote the below code to get the app version using substring function, but I am still unable to figure out a way to calculate the number of days it took the user to change from x.0 to x.1. Please help

```
DECLARE @t as DATE = '2020-02-25'

SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.USER_ID, LOGIN_DATE,
    SUBSTRING(user_agnt_str, 
              CHARINDEX(' version ', user_agnt_str) + 9,
              CHARINDEX(' ', user_agnt_str, CHARINDEX(' version ', user_agnt_str) + 9) 
                                            - CHARINDEX(' version ', user_agnt_str) - 10) AS APP_VERSION
FROM 
    [DB1].[dbo].[TABLE1]
WHERE
    (USER_AGNT_STR LIKE '%version %' OR USER_AGNT_STR LIKE '%Version %')
    AND CAST(LOGIN_DATE AS DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, @t) AND @t
    AND USER_ID IN (100033, 100056)
```

The output I get from this query is:

```
USER_ID LOGIN_DATE  APP_VERSION
--------------------------------
100033  2020-02-18  4.0
100033  2020-02-19  4.0
100033  2020-02-19  4.1
100056  2020-02-20  4.0
100056  2020-02-21  4.1
```

The output I am looking for should be:

```
USER_ID PREVIOUS_APP_VERSION    Current_APP_VERSION NUMBER_OF_DAYS
------------------------------------------------------------------
100033  4.0                     4.1                 0
100056  4.0                     4.1                 1
```

Comment: Why `100033` is `0` days ? Shouldn't it be 1 day (2020-02-18 to 2020-02-19) ?

Comment: @Squirrel: Since the App Version changed the same day, it is 0 days

Comment: `calculate the number of days it took the user to change from x.0 to x.1` Isn't that user is using version `x.0` in `2020-02-18` ?

Comment: Calculate the number of days between Login date when the app version changed from x.n to x.n+1